# Is there a difference between storing data in your program or a document file?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a text based game and was wondering if there will be any issues if I were to just write all the text in the code instead of making something like a csv file to read the data from. It won't be as organised, but I was wondering if the game would take more memory or have worse performance if I were to put the game in code instead of a text document or csv file.

Comment: Do you want to recompile code anytime you want to change your text?  You should _typically_ try to have the resources loaded in instead of hardcoded

Comment: Will you be localizing your game? (translating it into other languages, for example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some advantages and disadvantages:

#### In-a-file

- Easy to modify, easy to localize
- Not very secure, anyone can look at it and hack it
- Has to be parsed at runtime, what to do about errors if badly formed?
- Tiny performance hit on load (probably not worth worrying about)

#### In an embedded resource

- No separate file lying on the hard drive for your users to examine and hack (easily)
- Can localize fairly easily

#### In-code

- No need to parse the input file, syntax and structure is checked at compile time
- Can define your game resources using strongly-typed values, e.g. `Room cave = new Room("Cave", "Long description ...")`.
- Can define more complex relationships between objects without resorting to string-id references between them. `cave.ConnectsTo(passageway)`, `cave.Contains(sword)`, ...

In terms of memory consumption it's a wash - the strings will be in memory in either case - unless you are writing a huge game in which case a database would be more appropriate with the ability to easily load individual areas of the map and eject ones no longer needed from memory.

Comment: I agree with Ian here, but please let me add one more point to have in consideration. If you are planing on releasing future updates to the game you need to think about the size of the resources and how to apply those updates; if for example you have several translations and have some miss-spelled words you can easily deploy those as external file (small size), but if you have those in code you'll need to rebuild the exe and send the entire package.

Comment: External vs. Embedded are going to be largely the same, the only difference is whether or not the end-user can easily find the file (embedded files can--in theory--be extracted, modified, and reinserted, but it takes a much higher technical knowledge).